# Is this Sprite SVG possible to scrape?

Tags: python, svg, web-scraping, scrapy, sprite

Can I scrape this with standard Scrapy or do I need to use Selenium?

The html is:

```
<td class="example"><sprite-svg name="EXAMPLE2"><svg><use 
xlink:href="/spritemap/1_0_30#sprite-EXAMPLE2"></use></svg></sprite-svg></td>
```

I need the value "EXAMPLE2" somehow.

The xpath which works in the browser is //td[@class='example']//*[local-name() = 'svg']

When I put it into scrapy I use the following code but am getting XPATH error.

```
'example' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='example']//*[local-name() = 'svg'] 
()").extract()
```

Any ideas how to scrape it?

Comment: there is a dot in your xpath at the start. also can you share the site page url??

Comment: the page you linked here , in console $x("//td[@class='example']")  return empty array.can you check ?

Comment: How to figure which one is greyhound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the table, each svg sprite is under a class 'rug_X'

Something like

```
import scrapy


class RaceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'race'
    allowed_domains = ['thedogs.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://www.thedogs.com.au/racing/gawler/2020-07-07/1/the-bunyip-maiden-stake-pr2-division1']
    item = {}
    def parse(self, response):
        row = response.xpath('//tbody/tr')

        dog = a.xpath('.//td[@class="table__cell--tight race-runners__name"]/div/a/text()').get()
        
        number = a.xpath('.//td[@class="table__cell--tight race-runners__box"]/sprite-svg/@name').get() 
      
        cleaned_num = int(number.replace('rug_',''))
        grade = a.xpath('.//td[@class="race-runners__grade"]/text()').get()

        item = {'grade':grade, 'greyhound':dog,'rug':cleaned_num}
        yield item
```

You could also use item loaders with a custom function to clean up the response you get.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated my post with my code. Your code is giving me a list when I add it to my code, I only want one value for each greyhound.

Comment: I've edited the code to give you each greyhound with the number in the image. Is this clearer ?

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it with scrapy :

```
 response.xpath("//td[@class='table__cell--tight race-runners__box']/sprite-svg/@name").getall()
```

Working scrapy code :

```
import scrapy

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.thedogs.com.au/racing/gawler/2020-07-07/1/the-bunyip-maiden-stake-pr2-division1']

def parse(self, response):
    return {"nameList": response.xpath("//td[@class='table__cell--tight race-runners__box']/sprite-svg/@name").getall()}
```